# What's the verb to say 'feedback'?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, verbs

I mean feedback is a noun, but how do you say it in its verb state?

For example, in this sentence: how do I feedback the information to you?

How would you replace the feedback in that sentence above with a verb? 
thank you!

Comment: The noun ***feedback*** isn't a good candidate for "verbification". Use *give/get feedback* if you insist on keeping the word, but I can't really see the point. What's wrong with *How do I give the information to you?* (or more straightforwardly, *How do I inform you?*).

Comment: The noun _feedback_ is a nominalization of the serial verb _feed back_. So your example would be either _How do I feed the information back to you?_, or _How do I feed back the information to you?_

Comment: I would use the word "critique" if you mean that sort of "feedback".. rather than make a verb of feedback which tends to be heard and "repeat this back to me"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I feedback the information to you?

The context of the sentence above is unclear. I am unsure which of the two interpretations accurately portray your the context of your question.

> 1) You are trying to provide "feedback" to someone.
>
> **Feedback**
>   [feed-bak]/
>   noun
>
> 3. a reaction or response to a particular process or activity:

If this is the case, then I would suggest the following modifications.

> How do I **provide** feedback to you?

or...

> How do I **relay** the feedback to you?

---

2) You are trying "feed" information (not exclusively "feedback") to someone.

> **Feed**
>   [feed]/
>   verb (used with object)
>
> 6. to supply for maintenance or operation, as to a machine:
> 7. to provide with the necessary materials for development, maintenance, or operation:

This would be an informal corruption of feed, building off of the definitions cited above. Underlying this usage is an analogy; information:person :: paper:printer.

In this case, I would suggest the following modification.

> How do I feed information back to you?

Answer (score 2):

Personally I see nothing wrong with, in some cases, using the term as a verb, but split into two words.

***Would you mind feeding the results back to me, please***.
***The investigators fed back the information to the chair of the inquiry***

Indeed there is an entry in the OED, (sense 8e of the verb ***feed***) for ***feed back***. 8e(a) has to do with the electronic meaning, but 8e(b) is the sense:

> (b) In transf. sense also used intr. of a result or effect of a
>   process: to return as feedback; to affect or modify the process that
>   brought it about.
>
> 1940   Amateur Radio Handbk. (ed. 2) iv. 65/2   Care should be
>   taken..so that no output of this I.F. beat oscillator feeds back to
>   the input of the I.F. amplifier.
>
> 1945   Jrnl. Franklin Inst. 240 266   The y-shaft is driven by the
>   output of integrator II and feeds back to drive the input of the
>   function unit.
>
> 1960   R. W. Marks Dymaxion World Buckminster Fuller 23/2   Since the
>   benefits keep feeding back into the system, such techno-economic
>   patterns are infinitely regenerative.
>
> 1964   M. A. K. Halliday et al. Ling. Sci. x. 275   The experience
>   from the teaching of English to foreign learners is feeding back..to
>   the teaching profession in Britain.
>
> 1966   Rep. Comm. Inq. (Univ. of Oxf.) I. 56   There are also advances
>   in social studies, at postgraduate level, that are likely to feed back
>   into undergraduate work.

**But I would agree that it doesn't always work**.

Comment: Right. It's the nominalization of the serial verb _feed back_.

Answer (score 0):

***To [feedback](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/feedback)***: from Collins Dictionary:

> - (General Engineering) (tr) to return (part of the output of a system) to its input
> - to offer or suggest (information, ideas, etc) in reaction to an inquiry, experiment, etc

Feedback as a verb has the following usages: from Wiktionary

> (music) To generate the high-frequency sound by allowing a speaker to cause vibration of the sound generator of a musical instrument connected by an amplifier to the speaker.
>   - *The show ended with a riot of feedbacking guitars*.
>
> (transitive) ***To provide informational feedback to***.
>   - *His employees feedbacked him a lot more than he wanted.*
>
> (transitive) ***To convey by means of specialized communications channel***.
>   - *Customers feedbacked their complaints and some praise.*

Usage notes:

> - Some are likely to prefer "feed back" and its inflected forms "feeds back", "feeding back", or "fed back".

To [feed back](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/feed-back) from Cambridge Dictionary